# How to sort multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have tried almost all suggestions online, and I really can't figure out how to sort this SESSION array.
I want it sorted by "itemname"..

I have and want this output, but I need the itemname to determine which item array come first.

```
Array
(
[person] => Array
    (
        [namex] => Array
            (
                [itema] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 43
                        [itemname] => def
                    )

                [itemc] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 33
                        [itemname] => abc
                    )

                [itemg] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 29
                        [itemname] => ghi
                    )

            )

        [namey] => Array
            (
                [itemj] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 12
                        [itemname] => abc
                    )

                [iteme] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 44
                        [itemname] => jkl
                    )

                [itemr] => Array
                    (
                        [itemid] => 20
                        [itemname] => rst
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

So, "person" stays the same, but name, item, itemid and itemname is always different.

Can anyone help me sort this by itemname?
I need the array to be like this, so can't change it up.

Also.. I need to access it later in a foreach, so I can print out the items.

Comment: This may help you https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I have tried that.. Can't make it work :(

Comment: And how _exactly_ should the output look like? Asking because it currently is unclear how the name layer should be handled when sorting over the "itemname" column which is spread over multiple name entries. Please give the layout of the expected output array. There is an "edit" link below your question. _Use it_ to revise your question.

Comment: I dont really understand your question. I want to be able to get itemc[itemid] and same with itemname. I'm close to giving up, I am trying to implement the code suggestions, but nothing works.

Comment: I need the outcome to be sorted, when I echo each item out. And I need the order to be a-z from itemname, no matter what name its under.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments to the question the desired output is not really defined. You'd have to give a specific definition of the output, without that we have to *assume* what you *probably* are looking for:

```
<?php
$data = [
  "person" => [
    "namex" => [
      "itema" => [
        "itemid" => 43,
        "itemname" => "def"
      ],
      "itemc" => [
        "itemid" => 33,
        "itemname" => "abc"
      ],
      "itemg" => [
        "itemid" => 29,
        "itemname" => "ghi"
      ]
    ],
    "namey" => [
      "itemj" => [
        "itemid" => 12,
        "itemname" => "abc"
      ],
      "iteme" => [
        "itemid" => 44,
        "itemname" => "jkl"
      ],
      "itemr" => [
        "itemid" => 20,
        "itemname" => "rst"
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
foreach ($data["person"] as $personName => &$person) {
  uasort($person, function($a, $b) {
    return $a["itemname"] > $b["itemname"];
  });
}
print_r($data);
```

The obvious output is:

```
Array
(
    [person] => Array
        (
            [namex] => Array
                (
                    [itemc] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 33
                            [itemname] => abc
                        )
                    [itema] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 43
                            [itemname] => def
                        )
                    [itemg] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 29
                            [itemname] => ghi
                        )
                )
            [namey] => Array
                (
                    [itemj] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 12
                            [itemname] => abc
                        )
                    [iteme] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 44
                            [itemname] => jkl
                        )
                    [itemr] => Array
                        (
                            [itemid] => 20
                            [itemname] => rst
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input from the example is represented via array as:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'person' => [
        'namex' => [
            'itema' => [
                'itemid' => 43,
                'itemname' => 'def'
            ],
            'itemb' => [
                'itemid' => 33,
                'itemname' => 'abc'
            ],
            'itemc' => [
                'itemid' => 29,
                'itemname' => 'ghi'
            ],
        ],
        'namey' => [
            'itema' => [
                'itemid' => 12,
                'itemname' => 'abc'
            ],
            'itemb' => [
                'itemid' => 44,
                'itemname' => 'jkl'
            ],
            'itemc' => [
                'itemid' => 20,
                'itemname' => 'rst'
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

You could do use `array_multisort` in a loop:

```
$ids = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $newKey => $value2) {
        $ids[$newKey] = array_column($value2, 'itemname');
        array_multisort($ids[$newKey], SORT_NATURAL, $array[$key][$newKey]);
    }
}
```

This will output

```
array(1) {
  'person' =>
  array(2) {
    'namex' =>
    array(3) {
      'itemb' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(33)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "abc"
      }
      'itema' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(43)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "def"
      }
      'itemc' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(29)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "ghi"
      }
    }
    'namey' =>
    array(3) {
      'itema' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(12)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "abc"
      }
      'itemb' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(44)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "jkl"
      }
      'itemc' =>
      array(2) {
        'itemid' =>
        int(20)
        'itemname' =>
        string(3) "rst"
      }
    }
  }
}
```